# Optimal filtering algorithm for data structures

Tags: python, list, data-structures, data-manipulation

Lets say we have n basic elements in a python list: `[['A'], ['B'], ['C'], ['D'], ['E'], ['F']]`
Here n = 6.

We have a dynamic pair list (DPL) where these basic element are paired up. **No basic elements are paired up with itself and all DPL contains at least one occurrence of a basic element.**

For example, **few of the many possible DPLs** can be:

```
[
(['A'], ['B']), 
(['A'], ['C']), 
(['A'], ['D']),
(['A'], ['E']),
(['A'], ['F']), 
(['B'], ['C']),
(['B'], ['D']),
(['B'], ['E']), 
(['B'], ['F']), 
(['C'], ['D']), 
(['C'], ['E']), 
(['C'], ['F']), 
(['D'], ['E']), 
(['D'], ['F']),
(['E'], ['F'])
]
```

or

```
[
(['A'], ['C']), 
(['A'], ['D']),
(['A'], ['E']),
(['A'], ['F']), 
(['B'], ['C']),
(['B'], ['D']),
(['B'], ['E']), 
(['B'], ['F']), 
(['C'], ['E']), 
(['C'], ['F']), 
(['D'], ['E']), 
(['D'], ['F']),
]
```

or

```
[
(['A'], ['B']), 
(['A'], ['D']),
(['A'], ['E']),
(['A'], ['F']), 
(['B'], ['C']),
(['B'], ['D']), 
(['B'], ['F']), 
(['C'], ['D']), 
(['C'], ['E']), 
(['C'], ['F']), 
(['D'], ['E']),
(['E'], ['F'])
]
```

or

```
[
(['A'], ['B']), 
(['A'], ['E']),
(['A'], ['F']), 
(['B'], ['D']),
(['B'], ['E']),  
(['C'], ['D']), 
(['C'], ['E']), 
(['C'], ['F']),
(['D'], ['F']),
]
```

or

```
[
(['A'], ['E']),
(['A'], ['F']), 
(['B'], ['D']),
(['B'], ['E']),  
(['C'], ['D']),  
(['C'], ['F']),
]
```

and so on...

I want a function, that will take a DPL as the argument and return a list such that all pairs are distinct and each basic element occurs exactly once.

For example:

1.

```
[
(['A'], ['C']),
(['D'], ['F']),
(['B'], ['E'])
]
```

or

```
[
(['A'], ['D']),
(['C'], ['E']),
(['E'], ['B'])
]
```

are both valid outputs.

2.

```
[
(['F'], ['D']),
(['E'], ['C'])
]
```

or

```
[
(['A'], ['D']),
(['C'], ['E']),
(['E'], ['B'])
(['E'], ['C'])
]
```

are both not valid outputs.

Comment: your question is unclear : I would suggest  a source + a target + some explanations the way the target is aimed

Comment: Yes please edit the code of your attempt to solve this into your question.